# pdo not reading string from mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the following code for reading a `String` from a mysql function:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mydb;host=myhost", "myuser", "mypass" );

    $value = $_POST['myLname'];

    print $value ;
    //print $dbh ;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL check_user_exists(?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 50);

    // call the stored procedure
    $stmt->execute();

    print "procedure returned $value\n";

    echo "PDO connection object created";
    $dbh = null;

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This is not reading the returned value , however if I read the value usimg mysql* like :

```
<?php

$dbhost='myhost';
        $dbuser='mydb';
        $dbpassword='mypass';
        $db='mydb';

        $con=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); ;
        mysql_select_db($db,$con);
        $qry_str = "select check_user_exists('chadhass@hotmail.com')";

        $rset = mysql_query($qry_str) or exit(mysql_error());
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rset);
                mysql_close($con);
        foreach($row as $k=>$v)
        {
            print $k.'=>'.$v;
        }

?>
```

This returns correctly . ANy idea wha am I missing ?

function :

```
CREATE
FUNCTION `check_user_exists`(in_email
VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS varchar(1) CHARSET utf8
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE vcount INT;
DECLARE vcount1 INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO vcount FROM USERS
WHERE USEREMAIL=in_email;
IF vcount=1 then
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO vcount1 FROM USERS
WHERE USEREMAIL=in_email and isactive=1;
if vcount1=1 then
return('1');
else
return('0');
end if;
ELSE
RETURN('2');
END IF;
END
```

code that worked for PDO ::

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST);
try {
    $dbh = new PDO(PDO("mysql:dbname=mydb;host=myhost", "myuser", "mypass" ); 



    $value = $_POST['myLname'];


    $result = $dbh->prepare("select check_user_exists(?) as retval");
    $result->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 2);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass');
    $result->execute();
    $obj = $result->fetch();

print($obj->retval);




    echo "PDO connection object created";
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.17   Mysql   Client API version 5.1.49 
PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version 5.1.49

Comment: could be that I am overlooking something, it seems that you are not fetching any results after 'execute'?

Comment: following this example : Example #4 Calling a stored procedure with an output parameter
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
?>  from http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Please can you include the definition of `check_user_exists()`?  Specifically, is it a function that `RETURN`s a value (in which case you will need, as @DirkMcQuickly suggests, to fetch a record from the query's resultset: this is, after all, what you're doing in the `mysql_*` version); or is it a procedure with an `INOUT` parameter that is updated (in which case `$value` *ought* to be updated by the call)?

Comment: As mentioned, because it's a function that `RETURN`s a value, you will need to fetch the (sole) record returned by the query, as you had been doing in the `mysql_*` version.  However, if you were to change the function to a stored procedure, you could make the parameter an `INOUT` one and achieve what you had been trying to accomplish.

Comment: fixed it . The working code is added .

Answer (score 4):

The reason is, you aren't fetching the results from the query.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally getting my output params now.